# Confederate state debts

Tags: united-states

Confederate state debts, if interest was imputed, would be an enormous amount by  now. Why are they not recognized as legitimate? If the current US government collapsed and reformed, would the prior debts be discharged? What about state and municipal debts in the same situation?

Even if the political entities are dissolved, are the private individuals and their estates subject to liability for causing these damages,  especially if they made fraudulent statements indicating the debt would be repaid?

Comment: The confederate states stopped to exist with no state that emerged from them.

Comment: But actually, the individual states and persons still exist, just under a different umbrella. It is equivalent to conveyance in bankrupcty law

Comment: the entity of the *confederate states of america* ceased to exist. *Florida* just resumed the status of a member of the *united states of America* - the *CSA* and *USA* are distinct entities. Membership in either does not make a state liable for that government's debts.

Comment: That's like stripping the cash out of a company and forming a new one

Comment: @user33800 it's not an equivalent of conveyance.  States are not property.  Sovereignty implies that they only have those debts which they agree to assume.

Comment: But states contain property and it was conveyed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The debts of the Confederate States of America disappeared with the CSA

Basically, if you lend money to someone, and that person vanishes, you lose your money.

If the USA were to cease to exist as a political entity then the debts of the USA (bonds, currency etc.) would also cease to exist. Or, more accurately, there would be no one remaining who was responsible for or able to pay those debts. Whether any successor state(s) would honour them and to what extent would be a matter for negotiation between them and the USA’s creditors.

For the CSA, the [14th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution)  while most famous as the equal protection amendment also says:

> But neither the United States nor any State shall assume or pay any debt or obligation incurred in aid of insurrection or rebellion against the United States, or any claim for the loss or emancipation of any slave; but all such debts, obligations and claims shall be held illegal and void.

So, if anyone was going to honour the debts of the CSA, it wasn’t going to be the USA. In the end, no one did and the creditors lost their money.

Now, the debts of the individual states and citizens were not absolved because those entities continued their existence.

Comment: But if it's a confederacy (and not a sovereign) the debts should be split among the members of the confederacy

Comment: It's like if corporations form a federation and issues debt on behalf of them

Comment: @user33800 you mean like if shareholders form a company? They aren’t responsible for its debts either.

Comment: No. If corporations form a federation.

Comment: the confederacy was, a group of sovereigns that formed a different sovereign body.

Comment: Then it would be called a government and not a confederacy.

Comment: The confederacy was a government - albeit one recognised by virtually no one. Of course, if you choose to lend money to an organisation in active armed rebellion with its legitimate government you can’t really complain if you lose that money - it’s no different from funding any other criminal organisation.

Comment: In any case, whether such debts are in some theoretical sense still valid or not, the 14th amendment prohibited any state from making any payment on any such debt. It also declared all such debts "*illegal and void*". I don't see any meaningful sense in which any such debt was collectable from anyone after the ratification of the 14th